# EXCEL VBA: finding lowest value in column

Tags: vba, excel, min

i have tried to make select to pick column and find lowest value, but i dont know whats wrong:

```
mazas = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets("maping").Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Select)
```

I think the biggest problem is that i dont know lenght of column it can gave 3 number or 3000 numbers, but it will always start at C3. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about where the data ends, just skip the first two rows:

```
Sub NotTheFirstTwoRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("C3:C" & Rows.Count)
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(c)
End Sub
```

Because any blanks at the bottom of the column will be ignored.